# Android Constraint Layout Renderproblems in NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I´am trying to add my ConstraintLayout to a NestedScrollView.
When spectating my ContraintLayout everything looks fine.

But then including the layout to my NestedScrollView the collapses the ContraintLayout.(Even though I use match parent width/heigt on the include and in my CL)

This actually was a bug in a previous Version of the ContraintLayout (~pre Beta).[Google Bug Reports](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212141)

I´am following this approach with Verion beta4.[Link to Youtube AndroidDev Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XamMbnzI5vE)

constraint_layout.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="de.project.andy.aliver.JobCreatorActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_job_creator" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/jc_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

nested_scrollview_layout.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="de.project.andy.aliver.JobCreatorActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_job_creator">

    <include layout="@layout/constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 13):

Gosh...reserching for a hour without a Answer.
Creating a SO post and found answer after 5 minutes.

This problem discribed above is the same like in ScrollView. The Solution is to add

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to the scrollable parent.

So nested_scrollview_layout.xml will be:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="de.project.andy.aliver.JobCreatorActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_job_creator">

<include layout="@layout/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: for some reason  Android Studio (as of 2.3.1) does NOT auto suggest this attribute in NestedScrollView xml element, so I thought it is not supported. SO always here to help :)